# How to change loop of nested lists linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've faced with case where I have three nested loops and want to change them by linq. 
Example

```
foreach(var level1 in listL1.elements) {
foreach(var level2 in level1.elements) {
 foreach(var level3 in listL2.elements) {

  commonLevelList.Add(new Level() 
  {
     itemFromLevel1 = level1,
     itemFromLevel2 = level2,
     itemFromLevel3 = level3,
   });
  }
 }
}
```

Does it possible ? Thank you for advise

Comment: The lists are not nested, only your for loops.  To be able to compare lists there must be common elements and you combine the list with a JOIN.  Or a list is a child element of another list.

Comment: `ForEach` is not Linq.

Comment: Do you mean to have `level3` in `listL2` and not `level2`? Also, your code won't compile - you didn't close the call to `Add`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the `foreach` will lose a small amount of performance and make the code harder to follow, but based on your (probably wrong) question, here is the equivalent LINQ:

```
var ans = listL1.elements.SelectMany(level1 => level1.elements.SelectMany(level2 => listL2.elements.Select(level3 => new Level() { itemFromLevel1 = level1, itemFromLevel2 = level2, itemFromLevel3 = level3}))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I want. Can't understand why question is wrong.

Comment: `listL2` isn't nested so it isn't really `level3`, so either your variables are poorly named, or your question isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Linq:

```
var commonLevelList = 
    (from level1 in listL1.elements
     from level2 in listL2.elements
     from level3 in listL3.elements
     select new Level() 
     {
         itemFromLevel1 = level1,
         itemFromLevel2 = level2,
         itemFromLevel3 = level3,
     }).ToList();
```

Cartesian products are much easier to "digest" with query syntax (under the hoods, this uses `SelectMany` as shown in NetMage's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104853/767890)).

Comment: You aren't doing the same as the OP: `level2` should be `in level1.elements`.

Comment: BTW, I like the query comprehension syntax as it parallels the nested `foreach` very well. Note sure why I did this answer in lambda syntax.

Comment: @NetMage The OP is a bit of a mess, I can't really make much sense of the code he's posted. He can sort out what goes where in each `from` clause. The point of the answer is to show the query syntax which is decidedly more readable than `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're just looking to cross-apply.  If that's the case, its as simple as doing a join all, so you can do it with Join statements.

```
var commonLevelList = listL1.elements
    .Join(listL2.elements, a => true, b => true, (a, b) => new Level()
        {
            itemFromLevel1 = a,
            itemFromLevel2 = b,
        })
    .Join(listL3.elements, a => true, b => true, (a, b) => new Level()
        {
            itemFromLevel1 = a.itemFromLevel1, 
            itemFromLevel2 = a.itemFromLevel2,
            itemFromLevel3 = b,
        }).ToList();
```

just re-read the question and saw that they are nested, so SelectMany is the right one rather than join.  I was reading it as 3 independent lists.

It does beg the question though given the structure if you're guaranteed 3 levels or if this should actually be a recursive problem.